# how to use numpy-like vectorization properly to accelerate complex condition evaluation in pandas dataframe apply functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

numpy/pandas are known famous for their underlying acceleration, i.e. vectorization.

condition evaluation are common expressions that occurs in codes everywhere.

However, when using pandas dataframe `apply` function intuitively, the condition evaluation seems very slow.

An example of my `apply` code looks like:

```
 def condition_eval(df):
        x=df['x']
        a=df['a']
        b=df['b']
        if x <= a:
            d = round((x-a)/0.01)-1
            if d <- 10:
                d = -10
        elif x >= b:
            d = round((x-b)/0.01)+1
            if d > 10:
                d = 10
        else:
            d = 0 
        return d
df['eval_result'] = df.apply(condition_eval, axis=1)
```

The properties of such kind of problems could be:

1. the result can be computed with only using its own row data, and always using multiple columns.
2. each row has the same computation algorithm.
3. the algorithm may contain complex conditional branches.

What's the best practice in numpy/pandas to solve such kind of problems?

---

Some more thinkings.

In my opinion, one of the reason why vectorization acceleration can be effective is because the underlying cpu has some kind of vector instructions(e.g. SIMD, intel `avx`), which rely on a truth that the computational instructions have a deterministic behavior, i.e. no matter how the input data is, the result could be acquired after a fixed number of cpu cycles. Thus, parallelizing such kind of operations is easy.

However, branch execution in cpu is much more complicated. First of all, different branches of the same condition evaluation have different execution paths thus they may result in different cpu cycles. Modern cpus even leverage a lot of tricks like branch prediction which create more uncertainties.

So I wonder if and how pandas try to accelerate such kind of vector condition evaluation operations, and is their a better practice to work on such kind of computational workloads.

Comment: Can you provide example input data and expected output?

Comment: @BeRT2me I focus on performance rather than correctness, so it's ok to generate some test data. Or you mean to optimize the code according to the input data case by case.

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.apply(func, axis=1)` is just a nice wrapper for a for-loop. There is no parallelization nor vectorization when using it. Best practice is to use pandas/numpy vectorized functions wherever possible. [This Article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understanding-vectorization-in-numpy-and-pandas-188b6ebc5398) seems to give a good overview of the topic.

Comment: @BeRT2me Can I take the conclusion that when using `apply`, there won't be  vectorization optimization even the `apply` function only has simple basic math operations in it that could have been vectorized when write the code out of `apply`.

Comment: The so called 'vectorization' of `numpy` is about using compiled versus interpreted methods, not the low level use on SIMD etc.

Comment: @DaiZhang For `pd.Series.apply` and `pd.DataFrame.apply(func, axis=1)` that is a safe assumption.

Comment: @hpaulj any further explanation or related document about this, great thanks.

Comment: there are thousands of SO questions about 'eliminating for loops' in `numpy`, or equivalently 'vectorizing' this `numpy` operation.

Comment: In this recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830642/trying-to-improve-performance-of-some-vectorized-numpy-operations-via-cython, the OP is trying to improve on compiled `numpy/scipy` code using `cython`.  The answer delves into the low level performance issues - compiled optimization, parallelization, memory use.  So "vectorization" can mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: In your problem, the `pandas.apply` is notoriously slow, applying `condition_eval` repeatedly for each row of the frame.  The `df` your function gets is a 1 row dataframe.  Simply creating such a frame is time-expensive.  The answers on the other hand, work with whole columns of the original frame.  There are only 3 columns, but hundreds of rows.   The `df.x.le(df.a)` uses compiled methods (for arrays and series) to get a boolean series for all rows at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_eval_result(df):
    conditions = (
        df.x.le(df.a),
        df.x.gt(df.b),
    )
    choices = (
        np.where((d := df.x.sub(df.a).div(0.01).round().sub(1)).lt(-10), -10, d),
        np.where((d := df.x.sub(df.b).div(0.01).round().add(1)).gt(10), 10, d), 
    )
    return np.select(conditions, choices, 0)

df = df.assign(eval_result=get_eval_result)
```

My answer basically calculates the results of every branch, and then uses numpy syntax to specify which of those results should be used. This could be optimized slightly, but since it's using purely vectorized function, it should be far faster than using `.apply`.

Answer (score 0):

np.select is best for this:

```
(df
 .assign(column_to_alter=lambda x: np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3],
                                             [option1, opt2, opt3],
                                              default='somevalue'))
   
)
```