# Trying to improve performance of some vectorized numpy operations via cython

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I am trying to speed up a vectorized numpy operation by Cythonizing it (or atleast see if I can). The code calculates some sort of stress given two distance matrices (target_distances and map_distances computed from some flattened coordinate vector) and some information about distance types (it can range from 0 to 3 but for my first attempt I have taken it to be all 0 in this case). The numpy version is
pycalculus.py:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

def decay(x, s=10):
    
    return scipy.special.expit(s*x)

def stress(z, target_distances, dim, distance_types, step,
           nrows, ncols):

    row_coords = np.reshape(z[:dim*nrows],(nrows,dim))
    col_coords = np.reshape(z[dim*nrows:dim*(nrows+ncols)],(ncols,dim))
    
    map_distances = distance.cdist(row_coords, col_coords).copy()
    error = target_distances - map_distances
    
    I0 = (distance_types==0) | (distance_types==3)
    I2 = distance_types == 2

    return np.sum(error[I0]**2) + np.sum((error[I2] + step)**2*decay(error[I2] + step))
```

In the cythonized version, my pyx file is as follows (calculus.pyx)

```
import cython
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef extern from "ctools.h":
    double stress (double*, double**, int**, double, int, int, int)

@cython.boundscheck(False) 
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)     
def stress_cython(double[:] z, double[:,:] target_distances, int [:,:]
           distance_types, double step, int dim, int nrows, int ncols):
    
    cdef int i
    cdef int j
    cdef int N = (nrows+ncols)*dim
    
    z_C = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double)*N)
    target_distances_C = <double **>malloc(sizeof(double*)*nrows)
    distance_types_C = <int **>malloc(sizeof(int*)*nrows)
    
    for i in range(N):
        z_C[i] = z[i]
    
    for i in range(nrows):
        target_distances_C[i] = <double *>malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols)
        distance_types_C[i] = <int *>malloc(sizeof(int)*ncols)
        
        for j in range(ncols):
            target_distances_C[i][j] = target_distances[i,j]
            distance_types_C[i][j] = distance_types[i,j]
        
   
    stress_val = stress(z_C, target_distances_C, 
                        distance_types_C, step, nrows, ncols, dim)
    
    for i in range(nrows):
        free(target_distances_C[i])
        free(distance_types_C[i])
        
    free(target_distances_C)
    free(distance_types_C)
    
    return stress_val
```

And the external ctools.c is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double decay(double x){

    return 1/(1+exp(-10*x));
    
    }

double** dist_pairs(double* z, int nrows, int ncols, int dims)
    {

    int i,j,d;
    double coord1, coord2;
    double** dist;
    
    dist = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*)*nrows);
    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        dist[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols);
        }
    
    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++){
       for (j=0; j<ncols; j++){
            
            dist[i][j] = 0;
            
            for (d=0; d<dims; d++){
            
                coord1 = z[d*(nrows+ncols) + i];
                coord2 = z[d*(nrows+ncols) + nrows + j];
                dist[i][j] += pow(coord1-coord2,2.0) ;
                }
                
            dist[i][j] = sqrt(dist[i][j]);
        }
    }
                   
    return dist;
    
}

double stress(double* z, double **target_distances, int** distance_types, 
              double step, int nrows, int ncols, int dim){

    int i,j;
    double stress = 0.0;
    double err = 0.0;
    double **map_distances = dist_pairs(z, nrows, ncols, dim);

    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        for (j=0; j<ncols; j++){
        
            if (distance_types[i][j]==0 || distance_types[i][j]==3){
                stress += pow(target_distances[i][j] - map_distances[i][j],2.0);
                }
            else if (distance_types[i][j]==2){
                err = target_distances[i][j] - map_distances[i][j] + step;
                stress += pow(step,2)*decay(step);

            }
                
        }
    
    }

    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        free(map_distances[i]);
    }
    free(map_distances);

    return stress;

}
```

I do the following test (test.py)

```
import numpy as np
import time 
from calculus import stress_cython
from pycalculus import stress

nrows = 3000
ncols = 2000
dim = 2
N = 100
is_discrete = 1.0

dt0 = 0
dt1 = 0
difs = []
for i in range(N):
    coordinates = np.random.rand(dim, nrows+ncols)
    coordinates_flat = coordinates.flatten()
    
    target_distances = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)
    distance_types = np.zeros((nrows,ncols), dtype='i')
    
    t0 = time.time()
    stress1 = stress_cython(coordinates_flat, target_distances, distance_types, is_discrete, dim, nrows,
                   ncols)
    t1 = time.time()
    
    stress2 = stress(coordinates.T.flatten(), target_distances, dim, distance_types, is_discrete,
                     nrows,ncols)
    
    t2 = time.time()
    
    dt0 += t1-t0
    dt1 += t2-t1
    
    difs.append(stress1-stress2)

print(f'cython:{dt0:.2f} python:{dt1:.2f}')
```

and the timings end up pretty similar in my machine (~4.47 vs ~4.62). I am not quite understanding why, is there some parallelised computation going for numpy and scipy in the background?

When I check my core usage, it does not seem to be so. I tried turning of parallelism via

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

in the shell before running test.py and it did not make a difference. Is parallelism during vectorized operations is what I am missing here or am I just tring to optimize routines which already have been optimized to best possible extend in these libraries?

ps1: I compile cython code with the arg "-ffast-math"

ps2: In the end I will have all the cores engaged with different initial starting conditions so if numpy automatically parallelises vectorized operations, it wont help me. That is one of the reasons why I am trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: I suspect that you're trying to optimize things that are already pretty good. A general comment: "Indirect" arrays (like `double**`) are a pretty inefficient way of presenting an array. Consider using a single large array, and just translating the 2D indices to a 1D index - you'll find both lookup and allocation are faster.

Comment: Your python doesn't have any loops.  I suspect `distance.cdist` is the most expensive call, and that may be fast compiled code already.  I haven't used it much my self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compiler optimizations and instruction set

First of all Cython is often compiled with `-O2` which is generally suboptimal (vectorization is not enabled except for very recent version of GCC). `-O3` can give better performance. Moreover, the SSE instruction set is used by default on x86-64 processor while nearly all of them now support AVX (which is capable of computing generally 2x more items per cycle). Flags like `-mavx` or even `-mavx2` / `-mfma` can help to improve performance when supported (otherwise the target program can simply crash). You can use `-march=native` to let the compiler generate a non-portable program optimized for your processor. Numpy can detect this at runtime and use AVX instruction when needed (though it is not the case for all operations).

### Code issues

Operations like `pow(coord1-coord2, 2.0)` is not guaranteed to be optimized by the target compiler. It is certainly better to use `pow(coord1-coord2, 2)`, or even `(coord1-coord2) * (coord1-coord2)`.

A `double**` data structure is not efficient for storing matrices. It is better to allocate a big `double*` **flatten array** of size `width * height * sizeof(double)`. Indeed, the later has the benefit of being contiguous in memory and reading/writing contiguous data is generally faster. Furthermore, `dist[i][j]` can make inefficient indirection in memory while `dist[i*ncols+j]` can result in less/faster instructions. In fact, it is even more critical in parallel code since `malloc` tends not to scale with multiple cores so you should really avoid calling it many time in parallel.

`for (d=0; d<dims; d++)` is not efficient if `dims` is very small (like <8). **Unrolling the loop** for specific values can significantly improve performance. Alternatively, this loop can be swapped with the j-based one so to generate a faster code (possibly vectorized). It might be even faster to put it first.

> is there some parallelised computation going for numpy and scipy in the background?

Currently, Numpy should not parallelize any operation accept one based on BLAS (eg. matrix multiplications). As for Scipy, it is the same thing except some method can use multiple workers (quite rare, tunable and specified in the documentation).

Your code may be *memory-bound* (more specifically due to inefficient cache accesses) so the way of accessing data in memory matters a lot. Numpy can make more efficient accesses than your code.

Note that if the code is bound by the memory bandwidth, then it will not scale well (since using more core does not make memory access faster when the memory is already saturated).

### Further optimizations (update)

The Cython code spent a lot of time copying array for no reason since they are contiguous here. You can just pass it to the C function since the array are unmodified. Copying data is generally slow, especially large arrays.

It turns out that the compiler (GCC) simply fail to vectorize `dist_pairs` in practice even when `-O3` is provided (while Numpy does vectorize the code). I tried to modify the code to make the vectorization trivial but the generated code is inefficient even in this case. On solution is to write a vectorized code manually even though it make the code not portable anymore (only run on x86-64 processors supporting AVX, that is, nearly all desktop PCs that are less than 10 years old). Here is an example of (unchecked) code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

static inline double decay(double x){
    return 1/(1+exp(-10*x));
}

double* dist_pairs(double* restrict z, int nrows, int ncols, int dims){
    double* dist = malloc(sizeof(double) * nrows * ncols);
    
    if (dims == 2){
        // Fast 2D case
        for (long i=0; i<nrows; i++){
            int j;
            int z_offset_d0 = nrows;
            int z_offset_d1 = (nrows+ncols) + nrows;
            __m256d v_coord1_d0 = _mm256_set1_pd(z[i]);
            __m256d v_coord1_d1 = _mm256_set1_pd(z[(nrows+ncols) + i]);

            // Vectorized code for x86-64 processors
            for (j=0; j<ncols-3; j+=4){
                __m256d v_coord2_d0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&z[z_offset_d0 + j]);
                __m256d v_coord2_d1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&z[z_offset_d1 + j]);
                __m256d v_tmp0 = _mm256_sub_pd(v_coord1_d0, v_coord2_d0);
                __m256d v_tmp1 = _mm256_sub_pd(v_coord1_d1, v_coord2_d1);
                v_tmp0 = _mm256_mul_pd(v_tmp0, v_tmp0);
                v_tmp1 = _mm256_mul_pd(v_tmp1, v_tmp1);
                __m256d v_res = _mm256_sqrt_pd(_mm256_sub_pd(v_tmp0, v_tmp1));
                _mm256_storeu_pd(&dist[i*ncols + j], v_res);
            }

            // Remainder
            for (; j<ncols; j++){
                double coord1_d0 = z[i];
                double coord1_d1 = z[(nrows+ncols) + i];
                double coord2_d0 = z[nrows + j];
                double coord2_d1 = z[(nrows+ncols) + nrows + j];
                double tmp = (coord1_d0-coord2_d0) * (coord1_d0-coord2_d0);
                tmp += (coord1_d1-coord2_d1) * (coord1_d1-coord2_d1);
                dist[i*ncols+j] = sqrt(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        // General slow implementation
        for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++){
                dist[i*ncols+j] = 0;
                
                for (int d=0; d<dims; d++){
                    double coord1 = z[d*(nrows+ncols) + i];
                    double coord2 = z[d*(nrows+ncols) + nrows + j];
                    dist[i*ncols+j] += (coord1-coord2) * (coord1-coord2);
                }

                dist[i*ncols+j] = sqrt(dist[i*ncols+j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return dist;
}

double stress(double* z, double* target_distances, int* distance_types, double step, int nrows, int ncols, int dim){
    double stress = 0.0;
    double err = 0.0;
    double* map_distances = dist_pairs(z, nrows, ncols, dim);
    double step_decay = decay(step);
    
    for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++){
            if (distance_types[i*ncols+j]==0 || distance_types[i*ncols+j]==3){
                double tmp = target_distances[i*ncols+j] - map_distances[i*ncols+j];
                stress += tmp * tmp;
            }
            else if (distance_types[i*ncols+j]==2){
                err = target_distances[i*ncols+j] - map_distances[i*ncols+j] + step;
                stress += step * step * step_decay;
            }
        }
    }

    (void)err; // Avoid a compiler warning
    free(map_distances);
    return stress;
}
```

```py
import cython
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef extern from "ctools.h":
    double stress (double*, double*, int*, double, int, int, int)

# Assume Numpy arrays are contiguous
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def stress_cython(double[::1] z, double[:,::1] target_distances, int [:,::1]
           distance_types, double step, int dim, int nrows, int ncols):
    cdef int i
    cdef int j
    cdef int N = (nrows+ncols)*dim

    stress_val = stress(&z[0], &target_distances[0,0], &distance_types[0,0], step, nrows, ncols, dim)

    return stress_val
```

Here is the resulting time (with `-O3 -mavx -mfma`:

```
cython:1.29 python:4.45
```

Note that `dist_pairs` spent 60% of its time computing the square root. The rest is basically load/store from/to memory. The only way to speed up the square root computation is to 1. use an approximation or use less precise numbers (ie. `float`) or 2. use multiple threads.

You can make the overall computation less memory-bound by merging the loop of `dist_pairs` and `stress` and operating line by line (in an interleaved way). The computed lines can be stored in the fast CPU cache and instead of the slower main RAM. The resulting code should be compute-bound and scale very well.

If this is not enough, you can try to run this on *server-side* GPUs capable of computing double-precision operations efficiently since the square root should be computed faster and the device memory is also generally faster.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented all your suggestions. Compiler arguments do not seem to make much of a difference (in fact does not seem to make any difference at all). However changing double** to double* gives some slight improvement for matrices of smaller size 300x200 for instance where cython becomes about %10 faster, which is generally where my problem domain lies in. It becomes less or worse for larger matrices which is I guess where the memory-boundedness comes in.

Comment: @Sina I updated the answer. Please tell me if it is faster for you.

Comment: Thanks Jerome for the updated answer. I have tried moving the distance calculation inside the stress function and somehow it became slower. I was trying to understand how that came to be. My matrices are not that large so perhaps at that limit my problem is not memory bound, but at the worst scenerio I was not expecting any change. Unfortunately less precise sqrts would be a bit problematic for me so that is not an option. I have inlined the decay function though seems to help slightly.

Comment: Also how do you obtain that vectorized code? Most of my cases are 2D and 3D so would be interested to see if I could do something similar for 3D too. I did however unroll the dimension loop which did help.

Comment: In general loop fusion is faster when the memory accesses are an issue but it can break some compiler optimizations since the loop is more complex to analyse. The most frequent missed optimization is the use of SIMD instructions. That being said, GCC was already failing at this task on my machine without the fusion. If you use the optimize `dist_pairs` function using SIMD intrinsics, there should be no problem (unless some other optimization are broken but it would be a bit surprising here).

Comment: You can use SIMD instructions for the `stress` function too but this is not trivial to do. You need to compute both the `if` and `else` case and use `_mm256_blendv_pd` so to select the computed result based on the conditional vector. To build the conditional vector, you need either to use `_mm256_cmpeq_epi32` from AVX2 (if it is OK to use it) or use the non-256 SSE version. You also need to use the `_mm256_cvtepi32_epi64` function because `int` are 32 bit wide with GCC while `double` are 64-bit one (and SIMD lane have a fixed size).

Comment: This is a bit low-level but the thing is I do not expect GCC/Clang to vectorize this anyway yet. ICC (Intel compiler) may be able to do that though since it is pretty good to automatically vectorize codes (the compiler only supports x86 platforms too though AFAIK).

Comment: note that the `err = target_distances[i*ncols+j] - map_distances[i*ncols+j] + step;` instruction is often eliminated by GCC since `err` is not read later (ie. useless instruction). I got some issue with it when running/optimizing the code though: sometime GCC was not removing it causing the code to be significantly slower (typically when this line was optimized a bit). So maybe the same problem happens when you fuse the 2 loops. Note that setting `err` prevent many optimizations (if read later in the code) starting from vectorization since it creates a loop-carried dependency.

Comment: Is writing SIMD-intrinsics specifically for the 2D-case really necessary, or just because of GCC? Numba performance looks quite the same, if single-threaded (interleaved approach). https://pastebin.com/2SngE4zs What works in Numba should also work in Clang.

Comment: @max9111 I just analysed the generated code and it looks like `-O3 -mavx -ffast-math` should be enough for both compilers to generate some path properly vectorized. I think I got bad results due to `-O3` being overwritten by a `-O2` in the Cython setup tool command line (I remember timings was not great even once the bad `-O2` was removed)... For `stress`, GCC, Clang and ICC all generate an inefficient scalar code. Thus, intrinsics make more sense for `stress` than `dist_pairs` based on these results (or alternatively if both are merged with a granularity smaller than a row).

Comment: It was my first try using the https://github.com/vectorclass/version2. A fully vectorized approach for comparison (without remainder, algorithm unclear if distance_type==2) https://godbolt.org/z/3qcj8a7zn

Comment: @max9111 Good. Interesting! This make the code more readable and works even on machine not having AVX/AVX2. I tends to prefer intrinsics because of their flexibility (all instructions are available) but this is not important here. I just saw that the computation of the C code is not the same than the Python one regarding the `decay` call which is not a constant in the original code. This has a strong impact on performance since the exponential needs to be recomputed (as you did). The exp implementation seems quite efficient but I am wondering how precise it is.